# Attribute "left" sometimes doesn't work when calling chrome.windows.create?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, coffeescript

I was using this API in my extension like:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener (req, sender, msg) ->
  if req.word is 'open'
    popup =
      type: 'popup'
      url: 'build/select.html'
      left: 600
      width: 400
      height: 600
      focused: yes
    chrome.windows.create popup, (win) ->
      win.alwaysOnTop = yes
```

But many times I found the window was placed at the left edge of my screen. Is this API broken or something? How can I make it work?

My laptop runs Ubuntu 13.04, just hope it's not the problem.

Comment: that doesn't look like javascript to me. You should post your actual code.

Comment: https://github.com/jiyinyiyong/search-tab-crx/blob/master/lib/bg.js @kennypu it's CoffeeScirpt.. I thought people all know it. And here's the compiled JS code.